# CSS Background Image Blurry on mobile and tablet device

Tags: css, image, background

I have a background image on a local site that appears fine at desktop and when inspecting tablet/mobile devices in chrome. When site is loaded on mobile and tablet the background image appears incredible blurry to the point it looks terrible. Main image size is 1200px x 1124px. Any help would be great. CSS is posted below.

Thanks in advance.

```
background-image: url('../assets/Web_BGD.jpg');
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Have you tried to manually resize your image to something smaller and tested how it looks?

Comment: I would love it if you posted a demo somewhere.

Comment: LGSon - yes I have tried a smaller sized image for mobile, but that too gets very blurred.

Andy - http://codepen.io/marktaylor5/pen/LZVMVN